# WPF Drag & Drop of integer into datagrid of object

Tags: wpf, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have a datagrid in a window of my WPF MVVM Applicatiion, in another window I have a datagrid of another type of object.

As long as the two objects in the different datagrids matches, then there is no problem. But in this occasion I have two different objects in these windows.

What I want to do in my target window is that in my code behind change the object in the DragEvent to the object that matches the recieving grids object, something like this:

```
void dgdIngredient_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Data.GetData("**MyTypeOfObject**",true) as VMProductComponent) != null)
        {
            VMProductComponent vmp = new VMProductComponent();
            e.Data.SetData((e.Data.GetData(typeof(object)) as FOODit.Matilda.ViewModel.VMProductComponent));
        }
    }
```

However, the conversion always fail, and I allways get null in my GetData() statement, can anyone help me get this right, if it is even possible.

Thank you in advance.

/Peter

Answer (score 1):

Seems as though I had been working for too long, I was trying to convert my source object to my target object directly, so this is the correct solution.

```
    private void target_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  MyTargetType data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyTargetType)) as MyTargetType;
  if (data != null)
  {
    target.Content = data;
  }
}
```

/Peter